# Ordinary Differential Equations - square root issue

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I've been trying to solve the following problem:

[image: The problem]

I am not entirely sure how to approach this kind of equation.. do I separate the differentials and then integrate twice? or can i square root the whole deal?

I am not used to seeing this kind of marking of the power with a differential.

Any help appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to MSE! For your reference, here is a tutorial on how to type mathematics on this site: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}=y''$$
but
$$\frac{dy^2}{dx^2}=\frac{dy}{dx}.\frac{dy}{dx}=(\frac{dy}{dx})^2$$
$$(y')^2=\frac{1}{16-x^2}$$
$$y'=\pm\frac{1}{\sqrt{16-x^2}}$$
$$y=\int \pm\frac{1}{\sqrt{16-x^2}}dx$$

then integrate it by letting $x=4\sin u$

Comment: There should be a $dx$ in the R.H.S. of the last equation.

Comment: @Aniket thanks, I have added it

Answer (score 0):

Well, mb the following idea could help you to solve this DE:

1. Divide both sides by 16: $(dy)^2(1-(\frac{x}{4})^2) = (\frac{dx}{4})^2$
2. Make a substitution: $\frac{x}{4} = cos(t), \frac{dx}{4} = -sin(t)dt$